# Trying to invert output of nested for loop

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm trying to figure out the logic of this nested for loop. Functionally the code works, but the output should be inverted.

I've tried to play around with the logic of the nested for loop, but it always crashes my IDE. Also switching what the for loops print out does not give me the desired result.

```
public class stardot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" * ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (int k = 5; k >= i; k--) {
                System.out.print(" . ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output that I'm currently getting:

```
 *  *  *  *  * 
 .  *  *  *  * 
 .  .  *  *  * 
 .  .  .  *  * 
 .  .  .  .  * 
 .  .  .  .  .
```

This is the output that I want:

```
 *  *  *  *  * 
 *  *  *  *  . 
 *  *  *  .  . 
 *  *  .  .  . 
 *  .  .  .  .
 .  .  .  .  .
```

Comment: Try to rewrite if from scratch. You need one loop to handle amount of rows so it can look like `for(int row = 0; i<6; row++)` - and in each row you need to print some amount of start and dots, related to row number. What is that relation for start and dots? Which should be printed first?

Comment: @Pshemo should I post the solution? Or let he do it by himself?

Comment: @Pshemo oh well...

Comment: @LppEdd Point of most homework is learn *how* to solve family of problems, not just to see final answer of some specific case.

Comment: Have you considered running your program from a new terminal? That way you can just close the terminal, instead of waiting till your editor is restarted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution to your problem:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int k = i; k < 5; k++) {
                System.out.print(" * ");
            }
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--){
                System.out.print(" . ");
            }

            System.out.println();
     }
}
```

When figuring loops out like this, it helps to see the number of each character you need on each line. So for example, in the first line you need 5 asterisks, 0 periods. Then you need 4 asterisks and 1 period, then 3 asterisks and 2 periods, etc...

Then when you find out these values for each line, try to find a pattern. So we can see that when i is 0, we need 5 asterisks (5-i) and 0 periods(i - 0). When i is 1, we need 4 asterisks (5-i) and 1 period (i - 0). etc... From there, we can see what the structure of the for loops needs to be related to i.

Comment: Thank you, Connor, this was a helpful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing in text how you would go about drawing this pattern with a pencil.  Forget that this is a computer program, treat it as a logic problem. Something like (where '???' = excercise for the student)

```
for lineNumber = 1 to 6 {
    numberOfDots = ???
    numberOfStars = ???
    for s = 1 to numberOfStars {???}
    for d = 1 to numberOfDots {???}
}
```